# Git push doesn't work in ubuntu subsystem ( Permission denied (publickey) )

Tags: bash, git, github

I recently set up my SSH key to use it instead of HTTPS while working with git.
Configuration went completely fine but now when I am trying to use : **git push origin master**
in ubuntu terminal it doesn't work.
I get an error :

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**It is working in windows power shell and git bash.**
But I would like it to work in ubuntu (set up as subsystem for windows).

Comment: Did you add the _ubuntu_ public key aswell? (`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`)

Comment: You mean creating a new key as a second SSH key?
I followed along : [link](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) and all commends I ran in ubuntu

Comment: but yeah the folder is empty there idk why

Comment: Yeess that solution solved the problem I added second key for ubuntu.
It needed to be saved in /home/you/.ssh/id_rsa